# Question about bluetooth on Android

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth, uuid, ssp

Hi I just read your post [Bluetooth RFCOMM / SDP connection to a RS232 adapter in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953888/bluetooth-connect-to-a-rs232-adapter-in-android) and I think you probably can help me figure out my little problem.

I have this BT module connected to a MCU via serial port UART. Im trying to connect to the bluetooth via my android phone. I managed to use my app and scan BT devices. The scanner (based on BTchat) gives me the MAC. How can I know my device UUID ? It is SPP device also.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The device you are trying to connect to doesn't have a UUID from what I understand -- it is just the name and the MAC address. The UUID is used to uniquely identify the software service itself I believe.

The generic UUID for SPP is:

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

Let me know if you are able to connect, because I am still having issues.