# Sending bluetooth strings in android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Ok, so I have a bluetooth.java class which (i'd hoped) would send my strings.. however whenever I try to send the command my broken toasts just show saying nope. Am I missing something vital? I only have these 2 functions in there..

```
void openBT() throws IOException {

    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    try {
        mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to create socket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    try {
        mmSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to connect to socket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
}

void sendData2() throws IOException {
    if (BtCommand == "0"){
        msg = "Fan2 Off";
    }
    if (BtCommand == "1"){
        msg = "Fan2 On";
    }

    mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
}
```

and these are the only things I set

```
  BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
String BtCommand;
OutputStream mmOutputStream;
InputStream mmInputStream
```

I am sure it is the openBT function which is failing, I am paired to a device fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure with selected UUID?

[List of UUIDs](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.cz/2012/11/bluetooth-services-uuids.html)

Alternatively, try to rework your code. I use 2 threads (1 for connect and second connected and communication)

Comment: I am not sure no? I thought this uuid corresponded to all bluetooth devices, when I tried it, I tried between 2 android phones (SONY Z1 AND SONY Z5)

Comment: I am using 00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

Comment: Some quide : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964342/android-how-do-bluetooth-uuids-work
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953888/bluetooth-rfcomm-sdp-connection-to-a-rs232-adapter-in-android

Comment: It's not working still.. no idea why, I have even tried some random bluetooth terminal app's and they don't even connect

Comment: Try to test it on another phone (can be a problem with hardware or setup)